# How to ground a metal junction box with a 10/3 and a 12/2 wires going to the same panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding

I'm running 10/3 and 12/2 NM wires in the attic. Since my electrical panel is located outside, I have to switch to THHN wires into a junction box. I was wondering what the best way is to ground the metal junction box, since I have two different amperage going in the box—one for washer, other for dryer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What sort of conduit are you running the THHNs in?

Answer (score 5):

If metallic conduit, the conduit is a valid grounding conductor. In that case, use a 10AWG pigtail to the box grounding screw and join the grounds to the pigtail. If using non-metallic conduit, a single 10AWG ground is all that's needed in the conduit for the two circuits sharing the conduit. That should go to the box grounding screw first, and the other grounds should then connect to it.